# com.amazonaws.AbortedException while releasing dynamoDB lock

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am implementing dynamoDb locking in my code. I have a method which contains 2 ids and based on the 2 ids i create few entries in the table in dynamoDb. I have implemented the code as below (SAMPLE CODE):

```
Class Test {

public void testLocking() {

String pid;
String pid2;

//creating the lock and then using it as :

AcquireLockOptions optionsMain = AcquireLockOptions.builder(pid).build();
Optional<LockItem> lockItemMain = Optional.empty();
try {
 lockItemMain = lockClient.tryAcquireLock(optionsMain);
 if (lockItemMain.isPresent()) {

 // do some operation and store the object in dynamodb:

   dynamoDBMapper.save();

   } catch (LockNotGrantedException e) {
    //logging.
   }
   finally {
      if (lockItemMain.isPresent()) {
       logger.debug("Releasing the lock 1 :: ");
       boolean status = lockClient.releaseLock(lockItemMain.get());
       logger.info(LOCK_STATUS_STRING, status);
      }
    }
  }

AcquireLockOptions optionsTemp = AcquireLockOptions.builder(pid2).build();
Optional<LockItem> lockItemTemp = Optional.empty();
try {
lockItemTemp = lockClient.tryAcquireLock(optionsTemp);
if (lockItemTemp.isPresent()) {

// do some operation and store the object in dynamodb:

dynamoDBMapper.save();

} catch (LockNotGrantedException e) {
 //logging.
}
finally {
      if (lockItemTemp.isPresent()) {
        logger.debug("Releasing the lock 2 :: ");
        boolean status = lockClient.releaseLock(lockItemTemp.get());
        logger.info(LOCK_STATUS_STRING, status);
       }
      }
     }    
    }
   }
```

When this code runs I can see that the first lock is getting successfully released and the entry for the same is getting deleted from the lock table. But when it is coming to release the 2nd lock it is failing with exception :

> com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
>   at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.abortIfNeeded(SdkFilterInputStream.java:53) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.markSupported(SdkFilterInputStream.java:117) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1026) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3609) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3578) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3567) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeDeleteItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1161) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.deleteItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1132) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBLockClient.releaseLock(AmazonDynamoDBLockClient.java:631) ~[application.jar:?]
>   at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBLockClient.releaseLock(AmazonDynamoDBLockClient.java:581) ~[application.jar:?]

Not able to figure out the reason. Any leads would be appreciated !
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same error but when trying to create a Table, and it seems random